# Skeletal Animation With Assimp and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp, skeletal-animation

Recently I've been working on loading and playing skeletal animations in OpenGL using the Assimp library, following a few different tutorials/sources such as [OglDev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) and [Ephenation OpenGL](http://ephenationopengl.blogspot.com/2012/06/doing-animations-in-opengl.html). I'm still not 100% sure I know how it works, so just to clarify:

- The keyframes are loaded from the `aiNodeAnim`'s in the `mChannels` member of `aiAnimation`
- These keyframes are used to generate a per-bone matrix representing the transformation of the bone from its parent
- Each bone's matrix is multiplied by its parent's matrix
- This matrix is then multiplied by the corresponding bone's offset matrix, from `aiMesh->mBones[BONE]->mOffsetMatrix`. This way, the bone's matrix generated from the keyframes can replace the bind pose's default transformation for that bone
- This final matrix is used in the vertex shader when drawing (one for each bone)

The first part of my question: Is this correct? As far as I know, it should logically work, assuming my understanding is correct. I have yet to see any source/post/question that opposes this.

I have written an implementation of this (in C++), yet it's not working as I expected. Parts of the mesh look as they are supposed to, and are even in the expected pose, but most of the mesh appears crumpled. The large portions are distinguishable, and I can identify most of the mesh, but it appears that most of the bone matrices are incorrect. When I open my model in blender, all the keyframes are correct and the model animates perfectly. I would post screenshots of my application, but I do not have a place to do so (I don't have an imageshack account or anything.)

Is there any reason why only some of the bones would work and others not?

Here are the parts of my code that are most questionable. I based my `jawSkeleton` class on the `Model` class from LearnOpenGL.com. (Ignore the `jaw` prefix, it's a personal thing I do.)

Class prototype, in `jawSkeleton.h`:

```
class jawSkeleton
{
public:
        /*  Functions   */
        // Constructor, expects a filepath to a 3D model.
    jawSkeleton(GLchar* path);
    jawSkeleton();

        // Draws the model, and thus all its meshes
    void Draw();

        /*  Functions   */
        // Loads a model with supported ASSIMP extensions from file and stores the resulting meshes in the meshes vector.
    void Load(std::string path, bool bSmoothNormals = false, UINT unFlags = NULL);

private:

    bool Loaded;

        /*  Model Data  */
    std::vector<jawSkeletalMesh> meshes;
    std::string directory;
        // Stores all the textures loaded so far, optimization to make sure textures aren't loaded more than once.
    std::vector<jawSub_Texture> textures_loaded;
    jawSkeletalBone* RootBone;
    std::vector<jawSkeletalBone> bones;
    glm::mat4 Matrices[64];
    glm::mat4 GlobalInverseTransform;

    std::vector<jawSkeletalAnim> Animations;

        // finds a bone in the model data with the specified name
    jawSkeletalBone* findBone(std::string Name);
        // finds a bone in the model data with the specified name (Must be 'int' so that we can use -1 to denote no bone)
    int findBoneIndex(std::string Name);

        // Processes a node in a recursive fashion.
        // Processes the bones identified by the meshes
    void processNodeMeshBones(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene, std::vector<std::string> *BoneNames);
        // Populates the bone heirarchy structure
    void populateBoneHeirarchy(const aiScene* scene, std::vector<std::string> *BoneNames);
        //  Processes each individual mesh located at the node and repeats this process on its children nodes (if any).
    void processNodeMeshes(aiNode* node, const aiScene* scene);

    jawSkeletalMesh processMesh(aiMesh* mesh, const aiScene* scene);

        // Checks all material textures of a given type and loads the textures if they're not loaded yet.
        // The required info is returned as a jawSub_Texture struct.
    std::vector<jawSub_Texture> loadMaterialTextures(aiMaterial* mat, aiTextureType type, std::string typeName);

        // Load an animation for the model
    void processAnim(aiAnimation* Anim);

        // Updates the matrices for every bone
        // DOES NOT pull keyframes from the animation
        // Merely travels down the bone heirarchy and multiplies each child matrix by the parent matrix
    void UpdateBoneMatrices();
        // Updates the array of matrices that is sent to the shader
    void UpdateBoneMatrixArray();

        // Sets all the bone matrices to match a particular time
        // Before drawing, call UpdateBoneMatrices and UpdateBoneMatrixArray after calling this function
    void SetBoneMatrices(double Time);
};
```

Loading the keyframe data, in `jawSkeleton.cpp`:

```
void jawSkeleton::processAnim(aiAnimation* Anim) {
    this->Animations.push_back(jawSkeletalAnim());
    jawSkeletalAnim &_Anim = this->Animations.back();

    _Anim.Name = Anim->mName.C_Str();

    double TicksPerSecond = (Anim->mTicksPerSecond == 0.0) ? 1.0 : Anim->mTicksPerSecond;
    _Anim.Duration = Anim->mDuration / TicksPerSecond;

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < Anim->mNumChannels; i++) {
        aiNodeAnim* ThisAnim = Anim->mChannels[i];
        jawSkeletalBoneAnim BoneAnim;
        BoneAnim.Index = this->findBoneIndex(ThisAnim->mNodeName.C_Str());
        if (BoneAnim.Index > this->bones.size() || BoneAnim.Index < 0)
            continue;

        // Translation
        BoneAnim.TranslateKeys.reserve(ThisAnim->mNumPositionKeys);
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < ThisAnim->mNumPositionKeys; j++) {
            aiVector3D v = (ThisAnim->mPositionKeys + j)->mValue;
            BoneAnim.TranslateKeys.push_back(jawTranslateKey{
                glm::vec3(v.x, v.y, v.z),
                ThisAnim->mPositionKeys[j].mTime / TicksPerSecond
                });
        }

        // Rotation
        BoneAnim.RotateKeys.reserve(ThisAnim->mNumRotationKeys);
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < ThisAnim->mNumRotationKeys; j++) {
            aiQuaternion v = (ThisAnim->mRotationKeys + j)->mValue;
            BoneAnim.RotateKeys.push_back(jawRotateKey{
                glm::quat(v.w, v.x, v.y, v.z),
                ThisAnim->mRotationKeys[j].mTime / TicksPerSecond
            });
        }

        // Scaling
        BoneAnim.ScaleKeys.reserve(ThisAnim->mNumScalingKeys);
        for (GLuint j = 0; j < ThisAnim->mNumScalingKeys; j++) {
            aiVector3D v = (ThisAnim->mScalingKeys + j)->mValue;
            BoneAnim.ScaleKeys.push_back(jawScaleKey{
                glm::vec3(v.x, v.y, v.z),
                ThisAnim->mScalingKeys[j].mTime / TicksPerSecond
            });
        }

        // The BoneAnims member is an std::unordered_map
        _Anim.BoneAnims.insert(std::pair<GLuint, jawSkeletalBoneAnim>(BoneAnim.Index, BoneAnim));
    }
}
```

Preparing the individual matrices, in `jawSkeletal.cpp`:

```
void jawSkeleton::SetBoneMatrices(double Time) {

    // This is the function to edit

    jawSkeletalAnim& Anim = this->Animations[0];

    for (GLuint i = 0; i < this->bones.size(); i++) {
        auto Result = Anim.BoneAnims.find(i);
        if (Result == Anim.BoneAnims.end())
            continue;
        jawSkeletalBoneAnim &BoneAnim = Result->second;

        glm::mat4 T = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), BoneAnim.TranslateKeys[70].Value);


        glm::mat4 R = glm::toMat4(BoneAnim.RotateKeys[70].Value);
        glm::mat4 S = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), BoneAnim.ScaleKeys[70].Value);

        this->bones[i].CurrentMatrix = T * R * S;
    }
}
```

I do a few other things not shown, such as recursively multiply each bone's matrix by its parent's matrix and multiply them by their offset matrix. When I use the identity matrix in the place of the individual bone matrices, the mesh is drawn in its normal bind pose, so I'm almost certain this is not a mesh importing problem. And as I said, parts of the mesh look correct, so I'm guessing it isn't a skinning problem either. I've been looking into this one issue for about a week now. Any clue what's going on? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest that for testing you make a very simple mesh ( only two-three bones) and a very simple animation (two-three keyframes). That way you can see what works and what doesn't. Is the animation in left-handed coordinates?

Comment: Okay, I will do so once I have the time. No, it's in right-handed coordinates, just as OpenGL is.

Comment: Do you load COLLADA format or fbx ..or else? It should be noticed that even if you load by Assimp, there is a little different parsing approach for different format. I implemented my program to specify loading COLLADA, because fbx is more complex on processing. By the way, use glm and assimp in my experience, the matrix should be transformed by inverse and transpose, and COLLADA from blender should transform the global inverse matrix to left hand side.

Comment: @Tokenyet I am loading a COLLADA file from blender. As you said, I am using glm, and am using the `CopyaiMat` function from Ephenation OpenGL to fix the row/column order issue. I've experimented with transposing the matrices anyway and it only seems to make it worse.

Comment: If some vertices appear in the correct position, it means that your matrices are probably correct. So what's left? your per-vertex code. My guess is that the correct vertices are attached to one bone, and the incorrect ones are attached to more, and you are simply not using all bones correctly when there is more than one.